# Match contents surrounded by optional group in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how a particular Java regex should be written. The regex will be used in a sequence, and will match sections ending with `/`.

The problem is that using a simple split won't work because the text before the `/` can optionally be surrounded by `~`. If it is, then the text inside can match anything - including `/` and `~`. The key here is the ending `~/`, which is the only way to escape this 'anything goes' sequence if it begins with `~`.

Because the regex pattern will be used in a sequence (i.e. `(xxx)+`), I can't use `^` or `$` for non-greedy matching.

Example matches:

- `foo/`
- `~foo~/`
- `~foo/~/`
- `~foo~~/`
- `~foo/bar~/`

and some that wouldn't match:

- `foo~//`
- `~foo~/bar~/`
- `~foo/`
- `foo~/` (see edit 2)

Is there any way to do this without being redundant with my regexes? What would be the best way to think about matching this? Java doesn't have a conditional modifier (`?`) so that complicated things in my head a bit more.

**EDIT**: After working on this in the meantime, the regex `((?:\~())?)(((?!((?!\2)/|\~/)).)+)\1/` [gets close](http://fiddle.re/wtfna) but #6 doesn't match.

**EDIT 2**: After Steve pointed out that there is ambiguity, it became clear #6 shouldn't match.

Comment: And why a regex and not a utility method which will return whatever is needed?

Comment: The regex is required by the program framework we're using to match the entire text. It has to be a regex.

Comment: @Qix, Please see my answer.  I very well may be missing something, but I don't think what you're asking is actually possible to do, based on your restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is a solvable problem.  From your givens, these are all acceptable:

```
~foo/~/
~foo/
foo~/
```

So, now, let's consider this combination:

```
~foo/foo~/
```

What happens here? We have combined the second example and the third example to create an instance of the first example.  How do you suggest a correct splitting?  As far as I can tell, there's no way to tell if we should be taking the entire expression as *one* or *two* valid expressions.  Hence, I don't think it's possible to break it up accurately based on your listed restrictions.

Comment: See edit. This is perfectly possible. I'm not looking to use `split`; I just said `split` wouldn't work in this particular case.

Comment: I understand that.  I used split in the english sense.  Did you read my response?  Yes, you'll be able to match with regex, but based on your rules, the above combination can easily be either *one* or *two* expressions.  You may not be using `split()`, but you're still trying to separate expression, right?

Comment: I just re-read it. Very good point. If I assumed `~foo` and `foo~` will never match, does this make the regex possible?

Comment: Just tested in a sequence; you are very correct. Thank you for pointing out this logic; that saved me a few hours of headache. :) Although this doesn't directly answer the question I'm still marking it as such since it explained why my edited regex was doing what it did (correctly, I might add).

Comment: No problem.  The underlying issue is that there doesn't have to be anything in the beginning of an expression *and* there are multiple endings, some of which could also function as beginnings.  So, if there happens to be a `~` in front, it's impossible to tell when one expression ends (at least when you have a String of unknown length), and another begins.

Comment: Exactly. The docs will say these leafs cannot start with/end with `~` without a matching beginning/end `~`. This is not a hindrance at all, thankfully. :) Thanks again!